Abaqus CAE Fails to Launch via RDP/VNC on CentOS but Works with SSH and Physical Login
I'm experiencing an issue with launching Abaqus CAE or Abaqus viewer on a CentOS system when accessing it remotely via RDP or VNC. The software loads without problems when I log in physically or use SSH with display forwarding. However, when I try to run abaqus cae from an RDP or VNC session in the terminal, I receive the following error message: "Abaqus Error: Abaqus/CAE Kernel exited with an error."
Abaqus CAE and viewer GUI runs when accessed via SSH with X11 forwarding.
The abaqus GUI is what doesn't load. I can submit jobs from the command line.
